# Como reproducir audio correctamente en Flutter con AudioPlayers

Tags: flutter, dart, audio

Lo que intento hacer es reproducir un sonido cada vez que den click a un boton, el sonido es de 0:5 seg, el problema es que al presionar muchas veces seguidas el boton el audio no se reproduce las veces que dan click, como que se entrecorta.

```
    final playerSoundSlap = AudioPlayer();

 Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: _playSound,
                child: setImage != ""
                    ? Image(
                        image: AssetImage(setImage),
                        height: 80.h,
                      )
                    : const CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )),

 void playSound() {
    playerSoundSlap.play(AssetSource("soundsGame/slap-sound.wav"));
  }
```

Utilizo  audioplayers: ^1.1.1

Comment: Lo que deseas es poder escuchar los audios en "paralelo" por así decirlo, cierto? ya que si presionas muy rápido, el audiplayer estará bloqueado hasta que termine de reproducir el sonido actual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que al presionar clicks muy seguido, cuando intentas reproducir el sonido, el `AudioPlayer` se encuentra en un estado de "reproduciendo", por lo que ignora el "play", hasta que termine su reproducción.

Para eso se me ocurrió crear un "pool" de `AudioPlayers`, tú puedes definir el tamaño del pool, en este caso le puse `4` como ejemplo:

```dart
  
  // Define the Map of the AudioPlayers
  final _audioPlayers = <int, AudioPlayer>{};

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Define a Pool of AudioPlayers
    const pool = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < pool; i++) {
      // Create an AudioPlayer
      _audioPlayers[i] = AudioPlayer();
    }
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Dispose the AudioPlayers
    for (int i = 0; i < _audioPlayers.length; i++) {
      _audioPlayers[i]?.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  void playSound() {
    for (int i = 0; i < _audioPlayers.length; i++) {
      final currentAudioPlayer = _audioPlayers[i]!;
      // Find the AudioPlayer from the Pool which is not playing at this moment
      if (currentAudioPlayer.state != PlayerState.playing) {
        currentAudioPlayer.play(
          AssetSource("soundsGame/slap-sound.wav"),
          mode: PlayerMode.lowLatency,
        );
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Listo, messirve, Muchas gracias.